# For what website size does the deploy module make sense?

Tags: 7, deployment

I have a website that I am in the process of developing that I hope to grow to 1,000 active users or so by the end of the year.

I'm using the Features module to manage deployment, and a local-> dev-> staging-> production workflow courtesy of Pantheon.

Up to this point in my development, I've only been adding exportables that can be handled by Features.  However, I'm reaching the stage where I actually want to start allowing user-generated content which will not be managed by Features.

I've looked at the Deploy module, but it is 1) still under development for D7 and 2) has a quite involved setup.  I know that some of the big sites (Examiner, etc.) are using Deploy module workflows.

Are there use cases in which small sites would want to use the Deploy module?

Comment: Do you want use Deploy module to get user-generated content from staging site to your local or dev sites?